# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, invoke, invalidoperationexception

I am using a third party tool in which I get an InvalidOperationException (actually, in the end this occurs in PresentationFramework.dll):

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I tried any kind of variations using Invoke, including BeginInvoke, but nothing changes.

> Session session = new ThirdPartyTool.Session();
>   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => session.Open(view)));

When using Google I only find "solutions" that suggest to use Invoke. Well, I do use Invoke.
Other questions and their respective answer here on stackoverflow didn't help either.

What can I still do in order to track down the actual cause?

---

Edit:
I had another look into the thread window and the full call stack is in the main thread. AFAIK, this indicates the Invoke is superfluous.

---

Edit2:
The error isn't raised directly on calling open. The ThirdPartyTool initializes a list box and when measuring this list box the error occurs in the presentation framework:

[image]

The actual exception is wrapped into an XamlParseException. The full exception detail:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred  
HResult=-2146233087  
Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.  
Source=PresentationFramework  
LineNumber=0  
LinePosition=0  
StackTrace:  
  at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)  
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException  
  HResult=-2146233079  
  Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.  
  Source=WindowsBase  
  StackTrace:  
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()  
    at System.Windows.Freezable.get_IsFrozen()  
    at System.Windows.Controls.Image.UpdateBaseUri(DependencyObject d, ImageSource source)  
    at System.Windows.Controls.Image.OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)  
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)  
    at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ReceivePropertySet(Object targetObject, XamlMember member, Object value, DependencyObject templatedParent)  
    at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass6.<LoadOptimizedTemplateContent>b__4(Object sender, XamlSetValueEventArgs setArgs)  
    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnSetValue(Object eventSender, XamlMember member, Object value)  
    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx, XamlMember prop, Object value, Boolean onParent)  
    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(ObjectWriterContext ctx)  
    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx)  
    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()  
    at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)  
    at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)  
  InnerException: null
```

Comment: Is your code running in a background thread already?

Comment: Have you asked the ThirdPartyTool support?

Comment: @JeffRSon Not yet because I haven't been able to create a simple project which reproduces this error. In hope that someone of the broad audience here on SO has some good ideas, this is my first port of call.

Comment: Maybe they can do something if you provide the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Is there some initialization of ThirdPartyTool that takes place from a background thread? Or the first access to any part of ThirdPartyTool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that an image which was off my radar screen was causing the issue. Once we called `Freeze`, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 6):

I'd hazard a guess and suggest that you *don't* use invoke: just call `session.Open` from where you are.

I say that because - if your `session` object has thread affinity - you've just created it on whatever the current thread is, and so the `Open` call needs to be on the same thread.  Your `Invoke` is potentially pushing the call elsewhere.

Alternatively, it could be that some other code is causing the problem.  If that's the case then you could instead try this to *create* the object on whatever the dispatcher thread is:

```
Session session = null;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    (Action)(() => { 
                     session = new ThirdPartyTool.Session();
                     session.Open(view);
                   } ));
```

Comment: I agree to your first sentence. But I should have mentioned that my initial implementation just called session.Open and I tried to fix it by using the Invoke.

Comment: Are you definitely getting your exception from the `Open` call?  (Hint: if you have either "Just my code" or "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" enabled in your debug options, you might not be seeing the true source of the exception...)

Comment: The exception is thrown deep inside the open call. As mentioned in my question's first sentence, the exception is raised in .NET-Framework-Code (just fixed, though. I typed the wrong dll), and yes this is not displayed when I activate "Just my code". Unfortunately, the "true source of the exception" doesn't help me at all.

Comment: There's not much else can be suggested without more detail of what's going on.  Can you post the stacktrace of the exception, and some idea of what the third party component is?  Also, did you try my second suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I already did this when it was suggested in comments to the question. - I added some part of the stack trace. The full stack trace is about 95% presentation framework. The other 5% percent are the third party tool, where they create the list box and raise the "open"-event. The third party tool in question is ActiPro SyntaxEditor, but I guess this does not add any valuable information